# Setting 24-hour scale on Y-axis with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following list:

```
> head(myList)

     ID Day     Time
1 57790   0 12:27:41
2 66922   0 15:00:00
3 83457   0 18:22:37
4 83571   0 18:28:01
5 85613   0 19:06:05
6 93268   0 21:00:00
```

Comprised of these data types:

```
> myList %>% summarise_all(typeof) %>% gather()

   key     value
1   ID   integer
2  Day    double
3 Time character
```

Using `ggplot(myList, aes(x = Day, y = Time)) + geom_point()` produces the following plot:

[image]

As you can see, the Y-axis is all messed up. How do I get this axis to show only one mark for each hour in the 24-hour day instead of listing each individual Time value?

I have tied the various `scale_y_` functions, but I keep getting various themes on this error:  `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`.

Thanks for your help.

UPDATED - 10 Dec 17:00 CST

When using this code I get the following results:  Y-axis does not start at 00:00 or terminate at 24:00. Plots at 00:00-01:00 (top of the graph) should be at the bottom of the graph. It's SO close, though. :)

```
> myList$Time <- as.POSIXct(myList$Time, format = "%H:%M:%S")
> g <- ggplot(myList, aes(x = factor(Day), y = Time)) + geom_point() +
        scale_y_datetime(labels = function(x) format(x, "%H:%M", tz = "EST"), 
        date_breaks = '1 hour',expand = c(0,0))
> plot(g)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
myList$Time <- as.POSIXct(myList$Time,format="%H:%M:%S")
#Code
ggplot(myList, aes(x = factor(Day), y = Time)) + geom_point()+
  scale_y_datetime(labels = function(x) format(x, "%H:%M", tz = "EST"),
                   date_breaks = '1 hour',expand = c(0,0),
                   limits = as.POSIXct(c('00:00:00','24:00:00'),
                                       format="%H:%M:%S"),
                   date_labels = c('00:00','00:01','00:02','00:03',
                                   '00:04','00:05','00:06','00:07',
                                   '00:08','00:09','10:00','11:00',
                                   '12:00','13:00','14:00','15:00',
                                   '16:00','17:00','18:00','19:00',
                                   '20:00','21:00','22:00','23:00',
                                   '24:00'))+
  xlab('Day')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is ALMOST the answer. Using my full list, the Y-axis time scale extends past 23:59 (or 24:00), going to 02:00, with data plots going into 01:00. However, my data does not have any data passed 23:59 (`> max(myList$Time) = "2020-12-09 23:55:48 CST")`. Any idea why the scale /plots go beyond 24:00? Also, can you provide an explanation of why you used what you used?

Comment: (Updated) It looks like this is plotting the 1st hour (for days after day 0) at the end of the day, not at the beginning of the day.

Comment: @dave Hi dave, I have added an update, please check if that works and let me know!

Comment: Duck, see my updated post. Thanks for keeping with the problem.

Comment: @dave Added a new update, let me know if that works!

Comment: Duck, Yes, this worked! I did, however, change `00:01` to `01:00` etc. for the Hours. TBH, this is more complicated than I thought it would be for plotting day/time events.

Comment: @dave Awesome job! Yeah it is not a piece of cake plot but you got it :)

Comment: Duck - (FYI, i've tried, but `@Duck` doesn't work) I just ran into an instance where I have 100+ days, so the x-axis is getting crowded. How can I change the number of ticks /scale on the x-axis? I've tried using `lab` (from the par() function) but it throws an error, and `scale_x_date` requires x to be of type POSIXct, so that won't work either.

Comment: @dave Try increasing the date_breaks width like 5 hours.

Comment: Duck - In `date_breaks`, any numeric change over 1 throws an error. I am curious, though:  how will changing `scale_y_datetime` effect the X-axis?

Comment: @dave Hi dear, could you please invite me to chat https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187426/how-do-i-chat-with-another-user-on-stackoverflow I am glad to help you and we can address your issue in better way, as it looks like a data issue!

Comment: Duck, I tried to create a new chat room but the web an error page came up. Maybe later today...

Comment: @dave Sure, I will be there!

Comment: Duck, I changed `x = factor(Day)` to `x = Day` and then I was able to add `scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,21,2), expand = c(0,0), limits = c(-0.5,21.5), minor_breaks = seq(0,21,1))` and this worked. With `x = factor(Day)` I would get `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`. Thank you very much for helping me get this to work.

Comment: @dave Invite me to chat!

Comment: Duck, I can't. I don't get any links /buttons that allow me to initiate a chat or build a chat page. I was able to try once yesterday, but no more. I don't think SO likes me. :/

Answer (score 2):

check out the the various `scale_date` functions:

https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html

Here is an example using NYC Flight data and `scale_y_time()`. Note, I took the liberty of using `geom_jitter()` to better show the data.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

flightdata <- nycflights13::flights %>% 
  slice(1:3000) %>% 
  mutate(flight_time = lubridate::hm(paste(hour, minute)),
         flight_date = lubridate::ymd(paste(year, month, day))) %>% 
  select(flight_time, flight_date)

ggplot(flightdata, aes(x = flight_date, y = flight_time)) + 
    #geom_point() +
    geom_jitter() +
    scale_y_time()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm relatively new to R so I'm having difficulty extrapolating your example - using some other dataset - into my dataset and getting a plot.

Comment: `ggplot(myList, aes(x = Day, y = Time)) + geom_point() + scale_y_time()`